# Piped split command not executing

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection, split

Rather straightforward question that I'm stumped on. I have a command line utility called `twarc` that I am executing. This can build rather large files. I would like to leave this running and generating files of 5GB size for easier downstream processing. I am trying to run the following command:

```
twarc "wordlist" > outputfile.jsonl | split -b 5G
```

However, the file ended up at 10.4GB overnight. I can run `| split -b 5G` manually, but I would prefer not to.

I am using split (GNU coreutils 8.25) and the Windows Linux Subsystem.

Comment: because previous command's stdout written to file not to pipe

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand. Could you elaborate? Do I need to specify `| split outputfile.jsonl -b 5G`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up from the comment, the answer was in front of me the whole time!

The problem is that I was writing the command's stdout *to a file*, which effectively ended the command. In order to pipe it into split I needed to *not write to a file*. For example:

`twarc "wordslist" | split -b 1G`

Hope that helps someone down the line!

Comment: Thank you for following up with your own answer. Tomorrow (?) you can accept it too, to show that this was the answer that helped you most

Comment: The split is going to call your files `xaa, xab, xac ... xzz`. See man split for options to change both the base name and the extension length and type. Also note the -b option will split at byte count without regard for lines. If your output is text, the -C or -l options may be preferable as they preserve whole lines.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant yep, exactly! I have been playing around with those options to ensure that I can create legible output files. `split` is such a great tool!